# Почему код выглядит именно таким образом?

Tags: c, массивы, циклы

Задача - Вывести на экран все натуральные числа, меньшие заданного N, сумма квадратов цифр которых кратна 7, не понимаю строку `while(s += (t % 10) * (t % 10), t /= 10);` Что это могло бы значить?

```
int main() {
unsigned int i,n,s,t;

printf("введи n = ");scanf("%d", &n);

for(i=1; i < n; ++i) {
   s = 0;
   t = i;
while(s += (t % 10) * (t % 10), t /= 10);

   if(s % 7 ==0) printf("%d ", i);
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while(s += (t % 10) * (t % 10), t /= 10);
```

Здесь применен оператор "запятая", т.е. выполняются две инструкции, результат равен результату последней.

Сначала выполняется

```
s += (t % 10) * (t % 10)
```

т.е. к `s` прибавляется квадрат последней цифры `t`. Затем

```
t /= 10
```

`t` уменьшается в 10 раз. И результат деления используется как условие `while` - т.е. цикл завершается, если `t` становится нулевым... Тело цикла пустое.

Comment: а почему именно 10? это правило какое-то?

Comment: @КатяИзПространстваИнтернет, ну система счисления у нас десятичная.